# Encrypt a message using a public key in a file using openssl (virtualbox)

Tags: openssl, virtualbox, public-key-encryption

I have a question regarding the public key encryption. I have the public key of X and want to encrypt the message in the file message.txt using the public key of X stored in the file X.pub using openssl. I'm currently using virtualbox. 
I'm not sure how to import the public key of X. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: just copy / paste the key into the virtualbox or copy the message from the virtualbox. Where exactly do you have the problem?

Comment: Well I tried that but I cannot copy or paste the key. I tried the code below:                                                                                          openssl rsault -in message.txt -out encmessage.enc -pubin -inkey X.pub -encrypt

Comment: and what error / message do you get from the command

Comment: I'm getting the error "unable to load Public Key"

Comment: What does `file X.pub` get you? `.pub` is not a file format identifier...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have messed with your ssh public key.
If I am not wrong, regenerates it as PEM :

```
 openssl rsa -in <your ssh private key> -pubout -out X.pub.pem
```

and then encode your message with this public key :

```
openssl rsautl -in message.txt -out encmessage.txt -pubin -inkey X.pub.pem -encrypt
```